# Deploying Azure Function code with ARM/Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-marketplace

I am stuck with an issue where I want to deploy an Azure function and the code with Azure Resource Group but it seems this isn't supported? I followed the steps here and edited it to include an Azure Function project instead of the web app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-visual-studio-deployment-project#deploy-code-with-your-infrastructure

We are wanting to list an app in the market place that will deploy an Azure function into the customer's environment (and not our own) - hence assuming this needs to be a 'managed app' and needs the ARM/ARG template

Answer (score 0):

ARM can only be used to define the structure, but the deployment part still needs to use other methods.

Have a look of this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code

Comment: yea I thought Azure resource group could do..seems it can except for azure functions? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-visual-studio-deployment-project#deploy-code-with-your-infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-visual-studio-deployment-project#deploy-code-with-your-infrastructure)

Comment: @BruceAus From the document point of view, ARM does not support the deployment operation of azure Function.